# fgets causes C program to hang when run from bash on Windows, but works correctly when run from CMD or WSL

Tags: c, windows, bash, cmd, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm following a 'Build your own Lisp' tutorial to teach myself C, and came across some strange behavior related to fgets.  Here is a link to the Chapter I am working on: http://www.buildyourownlisp.com/chapter4_interactive_prompt#an_interactive_prompt

The code is a simple base for what will eventually be the REPL.  It just prints some info, and then starts a loop that gets and prints user input.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static char input[2048];

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        puts("Brenlisp Version 0.0.0.0.1");
        puts("Press Ctrl+c to Exit\n");

        while (1) {
                fputs("brenlisp> ", stdout);
                fgets(input, 2048, stdin);
                fputs(input, stdout);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

When I ran the executable from a Bash terminal (Windows 10), the program started but did not print anything to console, nor did it accept/print user input.

```
bschw@DESKTOP-92VUB1F MINGW64 ~/Projects/brenlisp
$ ./prompt.exe
```

However, when I ran the executable from CMD, the prompt performed as expected:

```
C:\Users\bschw\Projects\brenlisp>prompt.exe
BrenLisp Version 0.0.0.0.1
Press Ctrl+c to Exit

brenlisp> works fine
works fine
brenlisp> works fine
brenlisp> ^C
C:\Users\bschw\Projects\brenlisp>
```

Another curious thing is that when I run the program on WSL, it doesn't print the "^C" string to the console before exiting:

```
bschw@DESKTOP-92VUB1F:/mnt/c/Users/bschw/Projects/brenlisp$ ./prompt.exe
BrenLisp Version 0.0.0.0.1
Press Ctrl+c to Exit

brenlisp> works
works
brenlisp> works
brenlisp> bschw@DESKTOP-92VUB1F:/mnt/c/Users/bschw/Projects/brenlisp$
```

Why are these programs behaving differently depending on which shell they're being run from?  How could I get the program to work properly on Bash?

Comment: Try `fflush(stdout);` after the prints to (try and) force data to leave (eventual) buffers.

Comment: Thanks!  That worked.  I had to put it right after the first puts in the while loop
while (1) {
                fputs("brenlisp> ", stdout);
                fflush(stdout);
                fgets(input, 2048, stdin);
                printf("no you're a %s", input);
       }

Comment: Instead of `while (1)` you can use `while (*input != '\n')` to exit the loop when you simply press enter alone at the `"brenlisp> "` prompt. You only need 1 call to `puts` instead of 2, e.g. `puts("Brenlisp Version 0.0.0.0.1\nPress Ctrl+c to Exit\n");`

Comment: Also note, the `'*'` representing the level of pointer indirection (e.g. `char** argv`) generally goes with the variable, not the type (e.g. `char **argv`). Why? `char* a, b, c;` certainly does NOT declare three pointers, it declares one pointer and two character variables. `char *a, b, c;` makes that clear.

Answer (score 0):

In many implementations, the C Standard Library buffers output in internal buffers (*).

Often, for text streams, it does "line buffering" (buffers get emptied after dealing with a `'\n'`). This appears to be your case. Your output des not contain a newline.

To force the buffers to be emptied, use `fflush()` for output operations.

```
printf("not a line");
fflush(stdout);             // force buffer emptying

printf("complete line\n");  // line-buffering poses no issue here
```

---

<sup>(*) input streams may also be buffered, but the management of buffering for input is quite different</sup>